# How to change html header background image from base.html django

Tags: html, css, django-templates

I am extending base.html in Django and want to change the `<header>` tag background-image. I `{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}` but the background-image does not appear on child template. I wonder what seems to be error? I am inheriting base template using {% block header %} tag to insert a new `<header>` tag into the child template. The base template header I want to change the header background-image is the following.

```
<header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('static/assets/img/home-bg.jpg');margin-bottom: 0;padding-top: 21%;padding-bottom: 10%;">
            <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5" style="padding-top: 0;">
                <div class="row gx-2 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <div class="site-heading">
                            <span class="subheading"> Novel life hacks, tricks, skills and methods in all walks of life.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work through block template tag.
in `base.html`:

```html
{% block header %}
 <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('static/assets/img/home-bg.jpg');margin-bottom: 0;padding-top: 21%;padding-bottom: 10%;">       
            <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5" style="padding-top: 0;">
                <div class="row gx-2 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <div class="site-heading">
                            <span class="subheading"> Novel life hacks, tricks, skills and methods in all walks of life.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </header>
    {% endblock %}
```

and in `postdetail.html`:

```html
 {% block header %}
     <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url({% static 'assets/img/home-bg.jpg' %}); ; background-position: center; margin-bottom: 0;padding-top: 21%;padding-bottom: 10%;">       
            <div class="container position-relative px-4 px-lg-5" style="padding-top: 0;">
                <div class="row gx-2 gx-lg-5 justify-content-center">
                    <div class="col-md-10 col-lg-8 col-xl-7">
                        <div class="site-heading">
                            <span class="subheading"> Novel life hacks, tricks, skills and methods in all walks of life.</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </header>
    {% endblock %}
```